The SetDeadline of unix domain socket does not take effect
I am testing the behavior of uds unixpacket. Currently, I have encountered a very strange problem. Does anyone know the reason?
The uds client will write a message and then sleep until it closes the connection and ends after 60 seconds. The code is as follows:
addr := "/tmp/uds_socket"
client, err := net.Dial("unixpacket", addr)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Dial error:", err)
    return
}
defer client.Close()

message := strings.Repeat("A", 100)
_, err = client.Write([]byte(message))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Write error:", err)
    return
}

time.Sleep(time.Second * 60)

The uds server side will read the message twice. It is expected that the first message reading will be successful and the second message reading will be blocked. The test is also in line with expectations. Next, I don't want the second message reading to be continuously blocked. So I set a Deadline. It is expected that after exceeding the Deadline, the second message reading will fail. However, in the test, it is found that after exceeding the Deadline, the second message reading will still be blocked instead of failing. The code is as follows:
addr := "/tmp/uds_socket"
os.Remove(addr)

server, err := net.Listen("unixpacket", addr)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Listen error:", err)
    return
}
defer server.Close()

conn, err := server.Accept()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Accept error:", err)
    return
}
defer conn.Close()

var buf []byte

fmt.Println("now:", time.Now().String())
deadline := time.Now().Add(time.Second * 2)
err = conn.SetDeadline(deadline)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error setting read deadline:", err)
    return
}
fmt.Println("setting read deadline:", deadline.String())

temp := make([]byte, 1000)
n, err := conn.Read(temp)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Read error:", err)
}
fmt.Println("Read size:", n)
buf = append(buf, temp[:n]...)

fmt.Println("now:", time.Now().String())
deadline = time.Now().Add(time.Second * 2)
err = conn.SetDeadline(deadline)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error setting read deadline:", err)
    return
}
fmt.Println("setting read deadline:", deadline.String())

temp = make([]byte, 1000)
n, err = conn.Read(temp)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Read error:", err)
}
fmt.Println("Read size:", n)
buf = append(buf, temp[:n]...)

fmt.Println("Received message:", string(buf))

I have consulted some materials. Unfortunately, there is too little description of uds. Did I misunderstand SetDeadline?

Does it work as expected with a normal unix socket? (on macos here so don't have unixpacket to compare with)

I probably know the reason. I executed a piece of code in the code to obtain the buffer size, which will cause SetDeadline to fail. Reference:https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Fd    The code is as follows

connFile, err := conn.(*net.UnixConn).File()
if err != nil {
fmt.Println("File error:", err)
return
}
sendBufferSize, err := syscall.GetsockoptInt(int(connFile.Fd()), syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_SNDBUF)
if err != nil {
fmt.Println("SO_SNDBUF error:", err)
return
}
fmt.Printf("SO_SNDBUF: %d\n", sendBufferSize)
receiveBufferSize, err := syscall.GetsockoptInt(int(connFile.Fd()), syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_RCVBUF)
if err != nil {
fmt.Println("SO_RCVBUF error:", err)
return
}
fmt.Printf("SO_RCVBUF: %d\n", receiveBufferSize)

can you strace the server side and post the output ?
